# Find maximal k such that $y''+ky=\sin(x)\cdot\sin(6x)$ has no periodic solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation: $$y''+ky=\sin(x)\cdot\sin(6x).\tag{1}$$

I know that $$\sin(x)\cdot\sin(6x)=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(5x)-\cos(7x)).\tag{2}$$

The homogeneous solution is $$y_h:=A\sin(\sqrt{k}x)+B\cos(\sqrt{k}x).\tag{3}$$

I tried to define $A:=A(x)$ and $B:=B(x)$ and differentiate twice. Then I substitute the $y''$ and $y$ in the equation. I obtained the next equation:

$$(A''(x)-2\sqrt{x}B'(x))\sin(\sqrt{k}x)+(B''(x)+2\sqrt{x}A'(x))\cos(\sqrt{k}x)=\sin(x)\cdot\cos(x).\tag{4}$$

How to find the maximal $k$ such that equation $(1)$ has no periodic solution?

Edit #1:
I've found the particular solution if $k\neq 25$ and $k\neq 49$.
$$Y_P(x)=A\sin(5x)+B\cos(5x)+C\sin(7x)+D\cos(7x)$$
where $A=0$, $B=\frac{1}{2(k-25)}$, $C=0$, $D=\frac{1}{2(k-49)}$.
There are solutions when $k=25$ and $k=49$, when we use particular solution of type $(Ax+B)\sin(\sqrt{k}x)+(Cx+D)\cos(\sqrt{k}x)+...$

I didn't understand the task "to find the greatest $k$ such that equation has no periodic solution". So now I understand they just meant the number $49$.

Comment: You need to get a non-periodic particular solution, which only happens in the resonance cases $k=5^2$ and $k=7^2$.